# Como posso montar o ListView do resultado de uma chamada a API?

Tags: json, flutter, listview

Estou fazendo a chamada de um HTML e o retorno em JSON

```
var dadosJson = json.decode( response.body );
```

**é a seguinte string:**

```
flutter: resposta dadosJson: {_embedded: {banks: [{number: 001, name: BCO DO BRASIL S.A.}, {number: 003, name: BCO DA AMAZONIA S.A.}, {number: 004, name: BCO DO NORDESTE DO BRASIL S.A.}, {number: 021, name: BCO BANESTES S.A.}, {number: 025, name: BCO ALFA S.A.}, {number: 033, name: BCO SANTANDER (BRASIL) S.A.}, {number: 036, name: BCO BBI S.A.}, {number: 037, name: BCO DO EST. DO PA S.A.}, {number: 041, name: BCO DO ESTADO DO RS S.A.}, {number: 047, name: BCO DO EST. DE SE S.A.}, {number: 062, name: HIPERCARD BM S.A.}, {number: 066, name: BCO MORGAN STANLEY S.A.}, {number: 069, name: BCO CREFISA S.A.}, {number: 070, name: BRB - BCO DE BRASILIA S.A.}, {number: 074, name: BCO. J.SAFRA S.A.},
```

Mas não estou conseguindo carregar a lista somente com o numero e nome dos bancos.
A lista fica nula e dá erro de execução.

**Eu tentei assim, mas não carrega e dá erro:**

```
      List<Bancos> bancos = [];
      for( var listabanco in dadosJson ){
        print("nro banco: "+ listabanco["number"]);
      }
```

**Criei a classe Bancos**

```
class Bancos{

  String _number;
  String _name;

  Bancos(this._number, this._name,);

  String get name => _name;
  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }

  String get number => _number;
  set number(String value) {
    _number = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Coloque o código da sua `ListView`, caso não tenha feito nada aqui tem um exemplo: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: Muito obrigada!!